# How do I dynamically expand the range of rows/columns to which a chart takes the data from?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, charts, google-sheets-formula

I have the below pivot table, and i created the chart only with the data inside the table, excluding the bottom line with the totals and the right column with the grand total. If new rows automatically appear, how can I make sure they autimatically get added to the chart without having to add the bottom line as well?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

best option would be to use `FILTER` or `QUERY` formula on separate sheet or hidden columns to trim down your pivoted output and feed it to chart because charts do not support advanced formulae as an input

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to do that? I am not very practical with these things

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?